# Does terraform support math rounding?

Tags: rounding, terraform

Is it possible to round an integer value in terraform string interpolations?

Comment: The `ceil` and `floor` functions will perform rounding to integers if that's what you mean? If not you should give some examples of what you're trying to achieve with inputs and outputs clearly specified.

Comment: Take a string variable like "1.5" and round it up to 2.

Comment: Always up? You should edit your question to include a list of inputs and outputs. It might also help to explain some wider context of why you need this.

Comment: Converting gigabytes to whole megabytes for entering into spark property files.  Ceil and floor are helpful options but the values will be floats and not integers so using the external data source is more worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack and doesn't use terraform string interpolations but..

You can do this with the external data source (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) by delegating it to another program. The example I've included uses bash and jq. However you could probably achieve this without jq.

**Terraform:**

```
data external "rounder" {

  program = ["bash", "${path.module}/round.sh"]
  query {
    value="1.3"
  }
}

output "round" {
  value = "${data.external.rounder.result.value}"
}
```

**round.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exit if any of the intermediate steps fail
set -e

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "VALUE=\(.value)"')"

ROUNDED=$(printf "%.0f\n" $VALUE)

jq -n --arg rounded "$ROUNDED" '{"value":$rounded}'
```

Here is an issue about supporting "round" in terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16251

Comment: Didn’t consider an external data source script. Can leverage that for other things too. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use fomat for this now... check my answer

Answer (score 3):

There is another native terraform way of doing this, not sure if it's new but I just found it and thought I should add it here for reference:

```
format("%.2f", data.aws_ec2_spot_price.emr.spot_price)
```

This will return my spot_price as a 2 digit number, this uses the width operator in the [format function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/format.html)

> A width modifier can be included with an optional decimal number immediately preceding the verb letter, to specify how many characters will be used to represent the value. Precision can be specified after the (optional) width with a period (.) followed by a decimal number. If width or precision are omitted then default values are selected based on the given value. For example:
>
> Sequence   Result
>
> - %f      Default width and precision.
> - %9f         Width 9, default precision.
> - %.2f    Default width, precision 2.
> - %9.2f   Width 9, precision 2.

Comment: what a champ, to round to a whole number use  format("%.0f", number_you_want_to_round )